# Postgres GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA just hangs with no error messasge

Tags: postgresql

I am wanting to grant SELECT permissions to all tables on a schema in Postgres:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA sales TO newuser;
```

However, when I run this in psql, it hangs forever without any error message.

I have executed this same command on other schemas, and it executes and completes immediately.

There are many dozens of tables, views and materialized views in this schema.

Comment: Best guess is that there some activity on one or more objects in that schema that is holding one or more locks that are preventing the command from finishing. Take a look at [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) and [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm now seeing an error: tuple concurrently updated, after several hours

Comment: The error was thrown where? Have you looked at the contents of the table/views I posted earlier?